# Assign two values of the domain to a variable in one constraint

Tags: python, constraints

I've been having some trouble with a problem about cps in python. We have one constraint that asks us to assign 2 subjects (we have 6 in the domain) between 3 teachers, without repeating the subjects between them. The problem we have is that we dont know how to assign 2 values of the domain to only one single variable.

```
problem.addVariables(['Billy', 'Jannet', 'Julia'], ['CN','CS','L','I','EF','M'])
```

So what i dont know how to do is for example how to assign to Billy, the subjects CN and CS. I tried making a function that compares values and if are different return true, but it only prints something like this
Billy: M, Jannet: I, Julia: CN

Any little help would be apreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using dictionaries/tuples?

Answer (score 0):

You have the answer right in front of you: a list.  For instance,

```
Billy  = ['M', 'CS']
Jannet = ['I', 'L']
Julia  = ['CN', 'EF']
```

Since your names come in as strings, rather than variables, I expect that you'll want a dict instead:

```
{ 'Billy' : ['M', 'CS'],
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def addVariables(teachers, subjects):
  # convert ['CN','CS','L','I','EF','M'] to [('CN', 'CS'), ('L', 'I'), ('EF', 'M')]
  subjectPairs = zip(subjects[0::2], subjects[1::2])
  return dict(zip(teachers, subjectPairs))

print(addVariables(['Billy', 'Jannet', 'Julia'], ['CN','CS','L','I','EF','M']))
# prints {'Billy': ('CN', 'CS'), 'Jannet': ('L', 'I'), 'Julia': ('EF', 'M')}
```